# PHPmyAdmin Default Databases

Tags: phpmyadmin

Ok this is more of a 'Keeping my house in order' question.

PHPmyAdmin is installed but it has a bunch of databases installed as default.

•cdcol (1)
•information_schema (37)
•mysql (24)
•performance_schema (17)
•phpmyadmin (8)
•test
•webauth (1)

I recently deleted a bunch of these but after that I had lots of issues accessing PHPmyAdmin and had to re-install. Anyway long story short can I happily delete these without effecting my system?

Comment: Considering these tables contain things like user accounts and information about your databases, I'd say no. You might want to look up what these things do before deleting them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not all of those listed databases are `phpMyAdmin` related. Some are required for MySQL to operate normally.

- `performance_schema` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema.html
- `information_schema` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html
- `test` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/database-use.html
- `mysql` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//adding-users.html

`cdcol` Probably is for the cd collection sample database that comes with `XAMPP`. `webauth` is probably part of `XAMPP` as well.

The only `phpMyAdmin` related database (as you probably already guessed) is `phpmyadmin`, you can delete it, but letting it be there would improve performance, and add more functionality to the `phpMyAdmin`.

Answer (score 22):

Delete the cdcol database; it is just a sample.  For the other tables you mentioned, hide them from view by adding the following to config.inc.php.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db']='^(information_schema|performance_schema|mysql|phpmyadmin|test|webauth)$';
```

Comment: This is exctly the config I was looking for! +1

Comment: Very nice, alternatively you can set it in phpMyAdmin itself at `Settings > Features > General > Hide databases` and enter your value with regular expression.

Comment: very nice solution, exactly what i was looking for! +1

Comment: @vonUbisch Worth noting it's now `Settings > Features > *Databases* > Hide databases`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this via an automated script or command line:

1. Create a `hidedb.sql` file and add the following content:

   ```
   USE 'phpmyadmin';
   UPDATE `pma__userconfig` SET `config_data` = '{\"Server\\/hide_db\":\"(information_schema|performance_schema|mysql|phpmyadmin)\",\"collation_connection\":\"utf8mb4_unicode_ci\"}' WHERE `pma__userconfig`.`username` = 'phpmyadmin';
   ```
2. The Command line (or in a script - SAFER WAY):

   `$ sudo mysql -u root -p < hidedb.sql`

Of course you'll have to enter your sudo and then your mysql root database password.

If you're doing this in an automated script that you only can run as root:

**NOTE:** THIS IS **NOT A GOOD IDEA**! It exposes your root password!

```
DB_PWD="my_password"
mysql -u root -p"$DB_PWD" < hidedb.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

**2022**

You can just put the table names like this:
`information_schema|performance_schema|mysql|phpmyadmin|test|webauth`

Inserting `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db']='^(information_schema|performance_schema|mysql|phpmyadmin|test|webauth)$';` did not work for me.